# ubuntu ng commands wont work

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, angular-cli

Im trying to make angular-cli work in ubuntu.
So i installed it, but i run into a problem.

currently im working in root.

After i run `npm install -g angular-cli` and type `ng help` or any of the ng commands, i get the following in the console: ( tried `ng serve`)

[image]

Or with help command:[image]

What is that? how can i fix so ng work? how can i exit it?

Why is it not listing the ng help or any of the commands as it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I try

```
sudo apt remove ng-common
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/ng
```

and again

```
sudo npm i -g @angular/cli
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 4):

This issue was posted on git also https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3759

So the solution is - It looks like you have the ng-common package installed on your system, which also provides the ng executable.
It appears to be the Nihongo Micro Gnu Emacs editor. If you don't use it, or don't know it, it's probably safe to uninstall it using **sudo apt remove ng-common** and then remove node cache.
Try reinstalling angular/cli again.
If even after this it not works then give a path to in .bashrc or .profile
alias='path/to/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng'

or

Directly run every cli command with npm run e.g. npm run ng new app1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I install Angular CLI in my Ubuntu machine.
I received the message "successfully installed", but `ng --version` did not work.

I tried as follows and it works for me.

1. `npm link @angular/cli`
2. `export PATH="$HOME/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"`
3. ```
    npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
    npm cache clean
    npm install -g @angular/cli
   ```